# Countdown timer in UILabel in hidden UITableview section

Tags: uitableview, nstimer

I have an UIView in each section's header as a subview. That View contains start button and a label with countdown timer. 
So when the timer is started and the Tableview scrolls, some sections become hidden than shown again, it re creates my View and resets the timer.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

NSString *arrowName = [arrows objectAtIndex:section];

Workouts *workout = [workoutsArray objectAtIndex:section];

UIView* header;
if (section == 0) {
    header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 76)];
} else header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 68)];
header.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.133f green:0.125f blue:0.247f alpha:1.00f];

//The View with Timer Label
TodayWorkoutView* headerView = [[TodayWorkoutView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, header.frame.size.height-60, header.frame.size.width-32, 60)];
headerView.workout = workout;

[header addSubview:headerView];

return header;
```

}

How can I make timers in each section, that will work when TableView is scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution.

In viewDidLoad method init all Views and add to the new Array:

```
for (WeekDaysWorkouts *weekWorkout in [self getWokrouts]){

    Workouts *fullWorkout = weekWorkout.workouts;

    [workoutsArray addObject:fullWorkout];

    TodayWorkoutView* headerView = [[TodayWorkoutView alloc] init];
    headerView.workout = fullWorkout;

    [headerViewsArray addObject:headerView];
}
```

Then I added Views to the section view:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

NSString *arrowName = [arrows objectAtIndex:section];

UIView* header;
if (section == 0) {
    header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 76)];
} else header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 68)];
header.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.133f green:0.125f blue:0.247f alpha:1.00f];

//The View with Timer Label
TodayWorkoutView* headerView = [headerViewsArray objectAtIndex:section];

headerView.frame = CGRectMake(16, header.frame.size.height-60, header.frame.size.width-32, 60);

[header addSubview:headerView];

return header;}
```

So, all timers work without interruption, even when scrolling.

If anyone knows better solution, please let me know.